# Javascript inaccessible array in a nested function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a Parse function here that has a nested query. In the success function of the second query, I try to push to the array of the 'posts' property in the postsArray. However, I just get "Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined' in the callback. Is this to do with global variable scope? I can't figure it out, I'm not that experienced with javascript.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getPosts", function(request, response){

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

//Get all my bubbles
var postsArray = {};

var bubbles = new Array();
var query = new Parse.Query("Bubble");
query.equalTo("owner", request.user);
query.find({
    success: function(results){
        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            postsArray[i] = {};
            postsArray[i]["bubble"] = results[i];
            postsArray[i]["posts"] = {};
            //bubbles[i] = results[i];
            var members = results[i].get("members");
            for(var j = 0; j < members.length; j++){
                // posts[i]["posts"][j] = members[j];
                var postQuery = new Parse.Query("Post");
                //postQuery.equalTo("owner", members[j]);
                //postQuery.equalTo("members", request.user);
                postQuery.find({
                    success: function(results2){
                        for(var l = 0; l < results2.length; l++){
                            postsArray[i]["posts"].push(results2[l]);
                            if(l == results2.length-1){
                                response.success(postsArray);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        response.error("Failed");
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        response.error("Failed");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: You can't push to objects ?

Comment: The closure issue. In short, `i` will be equal to `results.length` when `success` callback of `postQuery` will be called.

Comment: Any ideas on how to overcome @raina77ow ?